# how to skip a service if names are the same

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services

I am new to the scripting world and am working on one to stop and start a series of Windows services remotely.

The issue I am having... I have a series of services that have like names till the end and need to be stopped in sequence.

Example:

> APPNAME_Service_1111
>   APPNAME_Service_1111_A
>   APPNAME_Service_2222
>   APPNAME_Service_2222_A

I was wondering how do I start/stop services `APPNAME_Service_1111` and `APPNAME_Service_2222` first then Start/Stop `APPNAME_Service_1111_A` and `APPNAME_Service_2222_A` second.

So something like if any service like `APPNAME_Service_%%%%_A` do second/last

I am using this script as a base.

```
@echo off

:choice
set /P c=This will stop X Services Are you sure you want to continue[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :stopservice1
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :end

goto :choice

echo "stopping services now"
:stopservice1
wmic /node:@list.txt  service where "name like '%%_service_%%XXX'" call stopservice

pause 
exit

:end

pause 
exit
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a list of the running services from `sc query`:

```
SERVICE_NAME: TeamViewer
DISPLAY_NAME: TeamViewer 10
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

then pipe to `findstr` to filter by the service name and the special tag `SERVICE_NAME:` just to be sure the correct lines are fetched and `/v /e` command line parameters in the first pass to exclude the postfix `_A` and only `/e` in the second pass to require it.

The code:

```
for %%a in ("/v /e" "/e") do (
    for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ('
        sc query ^| findstr "_Service_" ^| findstr "SERVICE_NAME:" ^| findstr %%~a "_A"
    ') do sc stop %%b
)
```

Comment: I fear that omitting any and all service names containing the string `_A` might not prove reliable. Perhaps it needs to be `_A` at the end of the service name. Even that might run into trouble.

Comment: @Liturgist, I don't see any possibility of that happening because `/e` looks at the ending of lines in the list of the matching service names. Pay attention to the `|` pipes and the actual values of `%%a`. However I forgot to extract the 2nd token, updated the answer.